# Refer to a sheet whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I need to refer to a sheet whose name is stored in variable `J`

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[-1]C,' " & J & " '!R32C1:R" & row_count & "C32,2,0)"
```

I am using the following formula but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the spaces after the apostrophes:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[-1]C,'" & J & "'!R32C1:R" & row_count & "C32,2,0)"
```

Comment: Yep this should work, note: if the sheet name doesn't have any spaces, then the apostrophes aren't needed at all.

Comment: @Wolfie True, but the apostrophes will always work, which is easier than testing the name - especially since it's not just spaces that make them necessary.

Comment: Yep, just making the comment, keeping apostrophes is the more foolproof method.